Ubuntu 24.04 is not detecting my integerated webcam
I have used many solutions but they doesn't work for me, the output of certain commands are-


I have runned this command

sudo dmesg | tail -n 30

but its giving this



Please don't post images of text. Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the formatting tools to format it as code.
